# Getting one or more values of anchor title attribute value in jquery/javascript

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have this html

```
<ul>
    <li class="size-bloc">
        <a  id="cat1" title="prod_1" data-url="" href="#" class="shoesize">
            <span>titre produits</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="size-bloc">
        <a  id="cat2" title="prod_2" data-url="" href="#" class="shoesize">
             <span>titre produits deuxieme</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to get title attribute value of the links when someone click on them.
When we click on the first  , i would like to get "prod_1" and when they move and click the second  to get "prod_2.

Something like

```
$myclass.each(function(e){
    // push the value in an array
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I would like to get title attribute value of the links when someone click on them.*

Bind a click event like

```
$("a.shoesize").click(function () {
    alert(this.title);
   //stop default action
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this -

```
$('a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent default action
  console.log(this.title);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var a;

  $('ul a').click(function() {
     a=$(this).attr('title');
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, may this but can I target the <u> element by the class ?

Comment: sorry dude, i can't get ur words, where u are using <u> dude?